# Is it possible to generate a hiberfil.sys without shutting down a computer?

Tags: windows, hibernate

I had an idea for a potential lifesaving program for people who work with important data and don't save frequently enough. By taking advantage of the Hibernate functionality on Windows, would it be possible to generate a hiberfil.sys without shutting down the machine afterwards to get a full image of Memory at regular intervals? If so, would it be possible to store this file somewhere, and potentially recover from a crash with the state of the computer just before the crash and continue as normal? Or is this a pipe dream, killed before it begins by some sort of security feature on Windows preventing "false" hiberfils from being loaded?

Comment: If you are using VMs, you can take a snapshot even when the machine is running which allows you to restore it to the state it was when the snapshot was taken. Obviously this only applies to VMs, so it's not really a solution.

Comment: It's a similar concept to what I'm hoping to achieve. Basically, I'd like to use the hibernate file to get this sort of snapshot functionality on a physical machine.

Comment: Interesting idea, but even if you get it to work I doubt it will do what you want: you will save memory, but not the file system (except those parts in memory). If you try to restore this image with a changed file system you are more likely to corrupt files than recover them. This is why Windows locks drives when it hibernates, to prevent updates if you boot an alternative OS. You should look at auto-save software instead.

Comment: If a system is generating a hibernate file its going into a power state other a power off state, so technically, the computer isn't shutting down.

Comment: constantly writing the contents of memory to disk would slow the system down significantly.

Comment: It wouldn't necessarily need to be constant, every few minutes would do.

Comment: @NathanShiraini - Note that a VM snapshot is of the entire virtual disc, so any restoration would include the whole of the file system, and restoration would be from a self-consistent image. Restoring from the hibernation file alone will not do this if there have been any file changes since the hibernation snapshot.